# Problem with writing a proper If statement

Tags: javascript

I have a page that passes some values using URL to input tag on another page. The problem that I have encountered was, that If there wasn't any value passed, there would be `undefined` as value, inside the input tag. So I was trying to write an if statement:

```
  if (params.name === undefined) {
    input.value = '';
  } else {
    input.value = params.name;
  }
  if (params.surname === undefined) {
    input.value = '';
  } else {
    input.value = params.surname;
  }
```

But as you can see based on this, it only works on, the `params.surname`, when I am passing `params.name` as a value, the input tag is clear. Any ideas how I could connect it together, so both values would show up, inside the input tag?

Comment: What output do you want when both values exist? `name surname`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance there can't be 2 values at once, it's either name or surname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `||` to alternate between the `name` (showing it if it exists), or the `surname` (showing it if it exists), or the empty string:

```
input.value = params.name || params.surname || '';
```

`params.name` will be inputted if it exists. Otherwise, `params.surname` will be inputted if it exists. Otherwise, it'll be set to the empty string.

If the properties can be the empty string, and not just `undefined`, and you'd want the empty string to be displayed if it exists, then use the conditional operator instead:

```
input.value = params.name !== undefined
  ? params.name
  : params.surname !== undefined
    ? params.surname
    : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more readable approach could be:

```
input.value = '';
if (params.name) input.value = params.name;
if (params.surname) input.value = params.surname;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
if(!(params.name || params.surname)){
  input.value = '';
} else if(params.name) {
  input.value = params.name;
} else {
  input.value = params.surname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, fun to play:

```js
  const resolve = att => params[att]? params[att] : '';
  input.value = resolve('surname') || resolve('name');
```

because `surname` has more priority than `name`, so in the assignment, `surname` should take the first place.

If you want `name` and `surname` both exist:

```js
  const resolve = att => params[att]? params[att] : '';
  input.value = resolve('surname') + resolve('name');
```